# How to get both rows as result from AWS lambda for For loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, aws-lambda

My code works for AWS lambda but the for loop seems to have something wrong. I have been trying but unable to figure out why i am getting only 1 row as output in the dataframe instead of 2 rows.

Here is my code -

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import boto3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from io import StringIO

result = []
df_test = pd.DataFrame()

url_list = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.google.in/']

for i in url_list:
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        options = Options()
        options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--single-process')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
        driver.get(i)
        title = driver.title
        result.append(title)
        
#        df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array(result).reshape(-1, 1))
        df_test = pd.DataFrame(result)

        bucket = 'bucketname'  # already created on S3
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        df_test.to_csv(csv_buffer)
        
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'df_test.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    
        response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "Selenium Headless Chrome Initialized" + title
        }
        
        return response
```

Comment: You've placed your `lambda_handler()` function inside a `for` loop. That for loop is not going to execute when AWS triggers your handler function. The handler function is the entrypoint into your code. Wrapping that in a `for` loop is bizarre, and just isn't going to work at all within the AWS Lambda runtime environment. The `for` loop should be inside the handler function.

Answer (score 2):

within the loop you're-initializing your df in each iteration of the loop, resulting in the DF with the data from the last iteration

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

you may instead create an empty DF before the loop and then append the df-Test to it.

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame()  # Empty DF, before the for loop

df_temp = pd.concat([df_test, df_temp], axis=1)  #replace the line where you're assigning to df_test
```

corrected the typo, df_temp subsequently will have both the rows

try and advise